# Pandas weird behavior using .replace() to swap values

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, replace

I stumbled upon a weird and inconsistent behavior for Pandas `replace` function when using it to swap two values of a column. When using it to swap integers in a column we have

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1]})
df.A.replace({0: 1, 1: 0})
```

This yields the result:

```
df
A
1
0
```

However, when using the same commands for string values

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': ['a', 'b']})
df.B.replace({'a': 'b', 'b': 'a'})
```

We get

```
df
B
'a'
'a'
```

Can anyone explain me this difference in behavior, or point me to a page in the docs that deals with inconsistencies when using integers and strings in pandas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup, this is definitely a bug, so I've opened a new issue - [GH20656](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20656).

It looks like pandas applies the replacements successively. It makes first replacement, causing "a" to be replaced with "b", and then the second, causing both "b"s to be replaced by "a".

In summary, what you see is equivalent to

```
df.B.replace('a', 'b').replace('b', 'a')

0    a
1    a
Name: B, dtype: object
```

Which is definitely *not* what should be happening.

---

There is a workaround using `str.replace` with a `lambda` callback.

```
m = {'a': 'b', 'b': 'a'}
df.B.str.replace('|'.join(m.keys()), lambda x: m[x.group()])

0    b
1    a
Name: B, dtype: object
```

Comment: I agree, the inconsistence is in the `Series.str.replace()` function. `DataFrame.replace()` raises an error correctly when you try `DataFrame.replace({'B': {'a': 'b', 'b': 'a'}})`, and `Series.replace()`, the version used for `int`, maps them in a separate array and then replaces the full column correctly. Somehow they forgot to keep `Series.str.replace()` consistent, the function is casting the `dict` into a ordered set and applying them in a certain order.

Comment: @Ricardo I've opened an issue, let's see what the devs say.