# How to swap two (string) values in a column using pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, replace

I'm trying to simultaneously `replace` values in a `pandas` `df`. For the `df` below I can replace `X` to `Y` and vice versa. But I have to do this at the same time. If I try to do this as separate functions, the result obviously swaps everything to the final function.

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({   
    'Col' : ['X','Y','X','Y','X'],
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['Col'] = df['Col'].replace(['X'], 'Y') 
df['Col'] = df['Col'].replace(['Y'], 'X') 

print(df['Col'])

0    X
1    X
2    X
3    X
4    X
```

Intended Output:

```
0    Y
1    X
2    Y
3    X
4    Y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue (and I believe is status-bydesign) - [swapping string values with `replace` results in counter-intuitive behaviour.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775130/pandas-weird-behavior-using-replace-to-swap-values)

In this case, my suggestion is to use `map` for element wise replacement.

```
df['Col'].map({'X': 'Y', 'Y': 'X'})

0    Y
1    X
2    Y
3    X
4    Y
Name: Col, dtype: object
```

If there are other possible values and you're only just swapping two, add a `fillna` call:

```
df['Col'].map({'X': 'Y', 'Y': 'X'}).fillna(df['Col'])

0    Y
1    X
2    Y
3    X
4    Y
Name: Col, dtype: object
```